# multiple arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have these arrays

```
$array_sku = {
[0]=> 'first'
[1]=> 'second'
[2]=> 'third'
}
$array_Title = {
[0]=> 'firstTitle'
[1]=> 'secondTitle'
[2]=> 'thirdTitle'
}
$array_Description= {
[0]=> 'firstDescription'
[1]=> 'secondDescription'
[2]=> 'thirdDescription'
}
```

I have a program in php that saves these informations in csv file like this:

```
| SKU  |     |   TITLE   |    |   DESCRIPTION    |
| first|     | firstTitle|    | firstDescription |
|second|     |secondTitle|    | secondDescription|
| third|     | thirdTitle|    | thirdDescription |
```

But now i have created new array, that have new suufixes (- BIG LETTERS)

```
$array_sku_new = {
[0]=> 'first-A'
[1]=> 'first-B'
[2]=> 'second-VG'
[3]=> 'second-RT'
[4]=> 'second-C'
[5]=> 'third'
}
```

I want to save these informations in csv in these way:

```
| SKU     |     |   TITLE   |    |   DESCRIPTION    |
| first-A |     | firstTitle|    | firstDescription |
| first-B |     | firstTitle|    | firstDescription |
|second-VG|     |secondTitle|    | secondDescription|
|second-RT|     |secondTitle|    | secondDescription|
|second-C |     |secondTitle|    | secondDescription|
| third   |     | thirdTitle|    | thirdDescription |
```

How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array_sku_new );$i++){
    $prod = array(
        'SKU' => $array_sku_new [$i],
        'TITLE' => $array_Title [$i],
        'DESCRIPTION' => $array_Description [$i],   
            );  
        $prods[] = $prod;   
}
```

It won't works good because all new skus don't have another information that they should.

Comment: adapt the php script you already have to the new input/output. What _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: i added ........

Comment: will the strings in $array_sku_new  always stard with first, second, third etc. and the capital letters will always be separated by a " - " ?

Comment: @FrançoisLanzeray 
1.no, first, second and third is just for an example
2.yes they always are separated with -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you might do this using your example data is making use if the hyphen and use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) in combination with [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset the keys.

Later on you can index into this array to get the amount of loops. To get the right index for `$array_sku_new`, `$array_Title` and `$array_Description` you can use the counter from the for loop and a separate counter to get the right index for `$array_sku_new`.

For example:

```
$totals = array_values(array_count_values(array_map(function ($x) {
    return explode('-', $x)[0];
}, $array_sku_new)));


$counter = 0;
for ($j = 0; $j < count($totals); $j++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $totals[$j]; $i++) {
        $prod = array(
            'SKU' => $array_sku_new [$counter],
            'TITLE' => $array_Title [$j],
            'DESCRIPTION' => $array_Description [$j],
        );
        $prods[] = $prod;
        $counter ++;
    }
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/rBV9n)

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot!